# How can I intercept the text to be inserted into a RichTextBox?

Tags: winforms, winapi

There is a TextChanged event for the RichTextBox, what I require is a TextChanging event so I have chance to perform an action before the text is changed.  The KeyDown event is not enough as my application uses a speech recognition engine which means it is possible to enter text without using the keyboard.

I was hoping I could intercept something in the WndProc method but nothing stands out.

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [TextChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) from the RichTextBox class. Based on the description from MSDN

> This event is raised if the Text property is changed by either a programmatic modification or user interaction.

It should be able to handle what you are trying to do.

---

Edit: You could have some sort of intermediary storage of the text so that when the text changes it is stored somewhere else first and after the text changed event is done, you can put the text back into the RichTextBox. But without knowing specifically what you are trying to accomplish, this would be my recommendation.